# Ruby: How do I find a letter in a string if only it is at the beginning of said string?

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I want to write a basic ABCs app as beginner programmer. I want to only see if the first letter in the user's input is correct, the reset of the word doesn't matter.

```
puts "What word starts with the letter 'A'?"  
ans = gets.chomp  
puts "Correct!" if ans.include? .......
```

I don't know how to evaluate only the first letter of the user's input. Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `string.start_with?(arg)` method.
http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F

```
puts "What word starts with the letter 'A'?"  
ans = gets.chomp                    # => 'apple'
"Correct!" if ans.start_with?('a')  # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "What word starts with the letter 'A'?"
ans = gets.chomp
puts "Correct!" if ans =~ /^a/i  # Case insensitive
```

Comment: `^` means beginning of *line* in Ruby, `\A` means beginning of *string*.